# Is Excelsior jet compiled apache tomcat server redistributable as part of an opensource project?

Tags: tomcat, jvm, compilation

I stumbled upon excelsior jet http://www.excelsior-usa.com/protect-java-web-applications.html
where in they have a compiled version of apache-tomcat which don't rely on jvm anymore. I know for sure apache-tomcat is open source and could be reditributed as part of your compatible opensource project. Now, I want to know if this compiled version is redistributable without hurting any constraint whatsoever, as part of your open source project. This compiled version offers an advantage without having to rely on sun's JRE. So theres a lesser file download and easier installation process.

Comment: I just tried this and it's painfully slow.  How did it go for you?

Answer (score 1):

It would have been a problem if Tomcat was licensed under the GPL or a similar license.

But the Apache license permits usage of the covered code in closed source software, whether commercial or not. There are at least two commercial Tomcat offerings: **[tc server](http://www.springsource.com/products/tcserver)** from SpringSource (now VMware) and **[Tcat server](http://www.mulesoft.com/tcat-server-enterprise-tomcat-application-server)** from Mulesoft, both containing proprietary code.

**Note:** To comply with the license, you must state that your product includes Apache-licensed code.